# Using PostgreSQL with QGIS and ArcGIS?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, postgis, postgresql, enterprise-geodatabase

Is it possible to use PostgreSQL with QGIS and ArcGIS? i.e. one database for different clients.

Is it anything that I have worry or any problems to use the DBMS from two different software?

I know that I need PostGIS and ArcSDE and I can't manipulate or store raster data with PostGIS 1.5 in PostgreSQL from QGIS.

What would you recommend or what to avoid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I sat in on a PostgreSQL/ArcSDE presentation ([link1](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc12/tech-workshops/tw_36.pdf), [link2](http://proceedings.esri.com/library/userconf/proc12/tech-workshops/tw_9.pdf)) at this weeks Esri conference and they talked a little about this.  They Esri product engineer said (at least I interpreted what she said) that:

- ArcGIS 10.1 only supports PostGIS 1.5
- ArcGIS 10.1 service pack 1 will support simple geometry features from PostGIS 2.0, but not advanced postgis features like topologies or raster
- In order to create an esri geodatabase on postgres, you will have to install the st_geometry library built by esri.  Users will NOT have to install this library if directly connecting to PostGIS geometry.
- 10.1 will allow users to connect to a spatial or non-spatial database the same way.  Nonspatial database connections are treated as equals to geodatabase connections.
- Store all of your tables and field names in lowercase.  (See page 43 of the linked presentation, and [What does 'DBMS table not found' message mean?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57666/what-does-dbms-table-not-found-message-mean)

From the sounds of it, if you want to do a direct connection to a PostGIS database (with simple features) you should be able to connect to the data through both ArcGIS 10.1 and QGIS.

Read more in the ArcGIS online help topic "[A quick tour of geodatabases in PostgreSQL](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_geodatabases_in_PostgreSQL/002p000000pt000000/)".

Comment: The links to the presentation are now broken, is there an updated resource?