# Why I see different data from PostGIS and ArcSDE

Tags: postgis, enterprise-geodatabase

I have installed ArcSDE 10 on PostgreSQL 8.4.3 with PostGIS 1.4.2. I did some tests.

1. I imported one feature layer with 8500 features into ArcSDE through ArcCatalog.  and I deleted 8499 features in ArcMap and just kept one. I saved the edits. I checked the data using PostgresSQL client tool, like pgAdmin III. I still see 8500 rows in the table.
2. I imported one feature layer with 3 point features into ArcSDE through ArcCatalog.  and I add 2 new points in ArcMap. I saved the edits. So I can see 5 points on this layer. But when checked the data pgAdmin III. I still only 3 rows in the table.

I closed and opened ArcMap and pgAdmin several times. and still see they have different data. Is anything I did wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You said you "imported" the data into ArcSDE.  To me that implies that you COPIED the PostGIS data and created a new dataset in ArcSDE.  Therefore you are no longer referencing the same dataset in PostGIS that you are in ArcSDE.

I think what you are trying to achieve is [connecting PostGIS to ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/147/how-can-i-connect-to-a-postgis-database-from-arcmap-9-3-and-10-0) or [connect to PostGIS through ArcCatalog](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6749/arcgis-and-postgis).  More than likely you will want to use an [ArcGIS Query Laye](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00s500000032000000.htm)r to interact with the PostGIS data. Or you could look into using the [ST-Links extension](http://www.st-links.com/Pages/default.aspx) (free).

What version of ArcMap are you using? 10.0 or 10.1?  At 10.1, there are [numerous enhancements](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30408/postgresql-for-qgis-and-arcgis-what-to-do-what-not-to-do) that make it easier to work with your PostGIS data directly.

Comment: We are still using ArcGIS 10.0 because we have a web application which is based on PostgreSQL 8.4.3, and now we want to add a map component into the application. Currently our GIS architecture is based on ArcGIS 10.0. That is why we decide to use ArcSDE 10.0 and PostGIS 1.4.2.
What we want to achieve is to store the spatial data into arcCGIS and then publish it to ArcGIS server. Then we can consume it through the ArcGIS javascript sdk.

Comment: I created a query layer based on the second test feature layer. I only see 3 points. What I dont get is I only see one table which has the feature layer name in DB when I creating the query layer or use pgAdmin. So I think I only have one table in PostGIS db. But if I view it through ArcSDE connection. I can see 5 points. Why there are referencing different datasets? Does it mean ArcSDE store the data in other place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your feature class in ArCatalog So,

1. Open ArcCatalog and open your database connection to see the feature class
2. Right-click on the feature Class
3. Select Register as Versioned

:D
and it will work correctly