# Error 'DBMS Table not found' when sharing some shapefiles as Runtime Content

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, error-999999, arcgis-runtime

I have a collection of shapefiles that I want to "Share as > ArcGIS Runtime Content". In this collection there are a few shapefiles that cause an error. If I access this function through the menu a "General function failure" is returned. Capturing the error in an ArcPy script is more informative:

> ... could not be compiled as a Runtime Geodatabase Package. ERROR 999999: Error executing function. Operation Failed
>
> DBMS table not found
>
> Failed to execute (CreateRuntimeContent)

I have looked up other posts involving "DBMS table not found" [What does 'DBMS table not found' message mean?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/57666) and [DBMS Table Not Found with SQLite and ArcGIS 10.3](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/173557)) and it seems this issue is associated with vectors shaped in database formats. Since my vectors are all stored in ESRI shapefiles, I am not sure why this error occurs.

The shapefiles seem to be intact when I load them in a map.